# Deploying to Heroku from Github with settings.json in .gitignore

Tags: security, meteor, heroku, github, settings

Since [Meteor free hosting](http://www.meteor.com) is going away, I'm trying to deploy one of my apps to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com). It seems to be good practice to deploy with a [Github](http://www.github.com) repository.

For security reasons, my `settings.json` is inside `.gitignore` and hasn't been pushed to my Github repo.

This didn't present any problem with Meteor hosting, since the `meteor deploy --settings settings.json` worked with the local file.

Now, with Heroku there are issues. Even using `heroku config:set METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"` doesn't work since it can't identify the settings file.

*Is there something wrong with this approach? Do I have to push `settings.json` directly to Heroku even with the integration active? If so how do I do this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku approach to this problem is based on their [12factor App](http://12factor.net/config) config philosophy (see the paragraph that starts with "The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables"). So the way to do this is to move your configs from settings.json to config vars. This would be an example:

```
heroku config:set MY_VAR=myValue MY_VAR2=myOtherValue -a myApp
```

It looks like the OP already knows this approach, he'll just have to take it for each key value pair in `settings.json`. The benefit of this approach is that if you bring more people onto the project, you don't have to find a way to securely transfer this info; authorized users can get the creds they need with `heroku config -a myApp`. You could also visit the [heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com) and add the settings via the web interface, if that's easier for you.